# Akka-Http client: How to get binary data from an http response?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I call an API to get a zip file response. The API responds correctly but I am unable to get the byte array from response because the future that should complete on getting the `ByteString` never completes:

```
    val authorization =  akka.http.javadsl.model.headers.Authorization.basic("xxxxx", "xxxxxx")
    val query = Map("fed" -> "xxxx", "trd" -> "yyy", "id" -> "zzz")
    val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri("https://xxxx.yyyy.com/ggg/ttt.php").withQuery(Query(params = query))).addHeader(authorization)
    val responseFut = http.singleRequest(request)
    responseFut1.map(response => {
    println("*******************************")
    println(response)
    response.status match {
      case akka.http.javadsl.model.StatusCodes.OK => {
        println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" + response._3)
        val entityFut = response.entity.toStrict(60.seconds)
        val byteStringFut = entityFut.flatMap(entity => {
          entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)
        })
        println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
        try {
          byteStringFut.map(x => {
          //this never prints =======================================problem     
            println("----------------------------" + x.toArray[Byte])
          })
        }catch{
          case e: Exception => println("Error: " + e)
        }
      }
      case _ => {}
    }
  })
```

If I print out the `response` this is what it looks like:

```
*******************************
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 20:58:43 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxxxx.zip", Pragma: public, Cache-Contr
ol: public, must-revalidate, Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary),HttpEntity.Chunked(application/x-zip),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^HttpEntity.Chunked(application/x-zip)
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

So response is coming back fine, but I still cannot get the binary data for the zip file.

We use akka-http in other places to call APIs that return json response and this approach seems to work fine there.
Why doesnt it work here? What am I doing wrong?

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks.

**Update**

Adding `byteStringFut.failed.foreach(println(_))` shows this exception: `akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: HTTP chunk size exceeds the configured limit of 1048576 bytes`

Comment: 1. Make sure that matching works. 2. if so, but the future never completes, then try to check if there wasn't thrown any exception with e.g. `byteStringFut.failed.foreach(println)`

Why do you match `response._1` instead of `response.status` or something like this?

Comment: @michaJlS: I have added more printlns and a try-catch to see the error. Matching works fine. No errors visible. As to why I used response._1: no particular reason other than I didnt know that response.status existed.

Comment: Try ... catch isn't useful here. You can see if Future failed or not using the snippet I've provided above. It could faild earlier.

Comment: @michaJlS: Thank you. I found the error, looked it up and fixed it in the config file. If you can post an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something went wrong and an exception was thrown in the async computation. You can check the exception by inspecting Future in the following way:

```
byteStringFut.failed.foreach(println)
```